# builtins.TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'method'

Tags: python-3.x, class, typeerror

I'm writing some code from a YouTube tutorial and I keep running into a type error. Why?

```
class Employee():
    ''' keeps track of company employees'''

    raise_amount = 1.04

    def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay 
        self.email = last + '.' + first +'@tech.com'

    def fullname(self):
        return self.first +' ' + self.last

    def Email(self): #not needed bc its already an attribute 
        return self.email 

    def raise_amount(self):
        return ((self.pay * self.raise_amount) - self.pay)    

    def annual_raise(self):
        self.pay = int(self.pay * self.raise_amount)
        return pay
```

Comment: You can't have `raise_amount` as both the name of a method, and the name of an attribute.

Comment: I can't believe i didn't notice that, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here , You have used the same name `raise_amount` for method and the class variable. When you execute the below code

```
 def raise_amount(self):
        return ((self.pay * self.raise_amount) - self.pay)
```

self.raise_amount will point to the method `raise_amount`. So the multiplication operation fails as it expects its arguments as numbers. You can either change class variable name or method name.

If you are changing class variable name, change the code as below:

```
raise_amount_value = 1.04
```

inside the method :

```
def raise_amount(self):
    return ((self.pay * self.raise_amount_value) - self.pay)

def annual_raise(self):
    self.pay = int(self.pay * self.raise_amount_value)
    return pay
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
class Employee():
    ''' keeps track of company employees'''

    raise_amount = 1.04

    def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay
        self.email = last + '.' + first +'@tech.com'

    def fullname(self):
        return self.first +' ' + self.last

    def Email(self): #not needed bc its already an attribute
        return self.email

    def raise_amount(self):
        return ((self.pay * self.raise_amount) - self.pay)

    def annual_raise(self):
        self.pay = int(self.pay * self.raise_amount)
        return pay

emp_1 =Employee("Joshua", "Ozoya", 9000)

print(emp_1.fullname())




your programme is running fine.

emp_1 =Employee("Joshua", "Ozoya", 9000)

print(emp_1.fullname())
```

Add those two lines of code to get the result.

And also, specify the error you were getting.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please fix your formatting. Also, notice that the question had already been answered in the comments. Finally, in order to show that your proposal addresses the question, please explain what your code does and how it solves the issue.